# java.lang.AssertionError: Status : 404

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

Please Could someone help me , I cant figure out what is the problem, I'am trying to implement a test to this method but it always gives me 
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :400

```
  @PutMapping("/infoUtile/update/{id}")
            public Map<String,Object> editActualite(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestParam ArrayList<Long> idDeleted,
                                                    @Valid @RequestParam String content, @Valid @RequestParam String description){
                InformationUtile info = this.infoUtileService.getInfoUtileById(id);

                    info.setContent(content);
                    info.setDescription(description);
                    info.setDate(new Date());

                if(idDeleted.size() != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < idDeleted.size(); i++) {
                        this.mediaService.deleteMedia(idDeleted.get(i));
                    }
                }
                InformationUtile i = this.infoUtileService.addOrEditInfoUtile(info);
                return getInfoUtileWeb(i);
            }
```

and here is my test that Im trying to implement

```
 @Test
    public void update() throws Exception {
        InformationUtile informationUtile = new InformationUtile();
        informationUtile.setId(1);
        informationUtile.setContent("oumaima");
        informationUtile.setDescription("test");
        Media medias = new Media();
        medias.setId(1);
        medias.setType("image/png");
        medias.setUrl("C:\\files\\actualite\\32769\\adobexd.png");
        List<Media> allMedias = new ArrayList<Media>();
        allMedias.add(medias);
        informationUtile.setMedias(allMedias);
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setNom("oumaima");
        informationUtile.setUser(user);
        ArrayList<Long> idDeleted = new ArrayList<>();
        idDeleted.add(0L);
        Mockito.when(informationUtileService.getInfoUtileById(Mockito.<Long>any())).thenReturn(new InformationUtile());
        Mockito.when(informationUtileService.addOrEditInfoUtile(Mockito.any(InformationUtile .class))).thenReturn(informationUtile);
        mockMvc.perform(put("/infoUtile/update/{id}",informationUtile.getId()).requestAttr("idDeleted",idDeleted)
                .param("content",informationUtile.getContent())
                .param("description",informationUtile.getDescription())
       )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        verify(informationUtileService, times(1)).getInfoUtileById(informationUtile.getId());
        verify(informationUtileService, times(1)).addOrEditInfoUtile(informationUtile);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(informationUtileService);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining three request parameters at your endpoint `@Valid @RequestParam ArrayList<Long> idDeleted, @Valid @RequestParam String content, @Valid @RequestParam String description` which means they are query parameters after the url, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/?idDeleted=1&idDeleted=2&content=Hello&description=Duke`.

The HTTP 404 indicates that Spring could not find a handler for your request, meaning the client (in your case `MockMvc`) has a malformed URL.

In your current `MockMvc` request setup you are using `.requestAttr()` for the `idDeleted` request parameter.

All of them should be `.param()`:

```
mockMvc
  .perform(put("/infoUtile/update/{id}",informationUtile.getId())
    .param("idDeleted", idDeletedOne , idDeletedTwo)
    .param("content",informationUtile.getContent())
    .param("description",informationUtile.getDescription())
  )
```

PS: I guess the `@Valid` annotations are redundant/not needed here as you are not checking e.g. payload which has Bean Validation annotations to verify the content.

**UPDATE:** `.param()` is overloaded with `.parm(String name, String... values)`, so you can pass your list of `idDeleted` with either `.param("idDeleted", idDeletedOne, idDeletedTwo)` or you can pass a `String[]` with all your `Long` values represented as a `String`

Comment: but in my case idDeleted is an ArrayList<Long> how can I express it @rieckpil

Comment: I tried to convert it but still give me 404 error , its like it only accepts the ArrayList<Long> @rieckpil

Comment: yes from Java perspective it is an `ArrayList` but if you model this in your URL it will look like the following `?idDeleted=100&idDeleted=200` or comma-separated is also working (https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-passing-list-and-array-of-values-as-url-parameters-1ed9bbdf0cb2). Can you try to debug your test and see what is the final target URL?